# Pygame: music do not play instantly on loop

Tags: python, pygame

First, sorry for my poor English.

I'm writing a game with `Python 3.4` and `Pygame`. Game includes scenes what provide view of screen, and music, etc, parsed from `XML` scripts.

I expect music plays instantly, but not plays at next scene.

and cannot find similar problem on web.

how can I rewrite code to play music scene-instantly?

I wrote code like it:
(graphic part removed)

xml file is here : https://pastebin.com/bSBiv1jX

```
import pygame
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class Script():
    def __init__(self, name, filename):
        self.name = name
        self.parsed = ET.parse(filename)
        self.root = self.parsed.getroot()
        self.scene_list = self.root.findall("scene")

        self.flag_list = str(self.root.findtext("flags")).split(",")
        for flag in self.flag_list:
            setattr(self, flag, False)

    def music_play(self, number):
        scene = self.scene_list[number]
        if scene.findtext("music") == 'stop':
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        elif scene.findtext("music") != '':
            pygame.mixer.music.load(scene.findtext("music"))
            pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

    def goto(self, number):
        string = self.scene_list[number].findtext("goto")
        if string == '':
            return number
        elif isNumber(string) == True:
            return int(string)
        elif isNumber(string) == False:
            return string

    def if_goto(self, string, number):
        iflist = string.split(', ')
        if getattr(self, iflist[0]) == True
            return int(iflist[1])
        else:
            return number + 1

def isNumber(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def runGame():
    pygame.init()
    windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True

    scene_number = 0

    script = Script('dummy', 'scenario/dummy.xml')

    while run:
        # 입력 처리
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if scene_number == script.goto(scene_number):
                        scene_number += 1
                    elif scene_number != script.goto(scene_number):
                        if isNumber(script.goto(scene_number)):
                            scene_number = script.goto(scene_number)
                        else:
                            scene_number = script.if_goto(script.goto(scene_number), scene_number)

        script.music_play(scene_number)

        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(30)
    pygame.quit()

def main():
    runGame()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.load

> If a music stream is already playing it will be stopped

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play

> If the music is already playing it will be restarted.

At every iteration of your game loop you call `music_play` and restart the music. You should only start the music if it's not already running.

You could, for instance, only call this when a scene changes.

Comment: I understood. music ran repeat very fast at scene 0, and stopped to run music at scene 1. is it right?